# What kind of wild South Carolina shrub is this?

Tags: shrubs

Zone 8B coastal South Carolina. There were quite a few of these out in the field, small seeds, no flowers visible.

[image: Whole plant]

[image: Leaves]

Full size photos here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J4cj.jpg

Comment: You mentioned small seeds, but I actually don't see any seeds in either picture, even when I zoomed in on the full size photos. Can you add a close-up of the seeds (or just circle them in the photo)?

Comment: @csk they were on the ground, looked kinda like sunflower seeds but extremely thin.